# Gitlab CI/CD: Publishing the result of build stage onto another stage

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm building a CI/CD pipeline with Gitlab CI/CD.

`.gitlab-ci.yml` -

```
build:
    image: node:16-alpine
    stage: build
    script:
        - yarn install
        - yarn build
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - //something here
```

I have a `build` job which builds the app. In the next job when deploying the app, I need the build directory from the previous job that is `build`.

How to I publish this as an artifact?

Answer (score 0):

I`m do

```
  needs:
    - job: "build"
      artifacts: true
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest #docker image
  script:
    - echo "release job"
  release:
    name: 'Release Executables $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA'
    description: 'Created using the release-cli'
    tag_name: '$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA'
    assets:
      links:
        - name: 'comment one'
          url: 'https://my.gitlab.my/you/project/-/jobs/${GE_JOB_ID}/artifacts/path to file'
```

result search Release!